# Mysql not returning same records for date_format function

Tags: mysql, resultset, date-format, minute

I'm facing a problem with this request :

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s') as dateHeureNow;`

The query in Mysql gives me the exact time and minute corresponding to the server execution time. However, when I execute it from java the resultset always return a value in which hour is equal to minute. It seems to be a problem while converting `%i`.
I'm hitting the same server.

Can you help me?

Comment: always 04 and always 09 or is that just representative of running on the same "time?" Are you sure you're hitting the same server (do the servers have different times?)

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I misspoke. The query in Mysql gives me the exact time and minute corresponding to my execution time (Forexemple when I execute now , I'll have : 22-11-2016 04:46:31. In java, the time is always equal to the minute ( I have 22-11-2016 04:04:31). I'm hitting the same server.

Comment: Try this what you get? `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d-%m-%Y %r')`